# Find and load cached Image in Glide

Tags: caching, universal-image-loader, android-glide

I am new in glide and want to migrate my app from universalimageloader to glide.
I want to convert cached image from the disk into image file, and show it into an ImageView.

When I use universalimageloader, I can do it easily with this way:

```
File imageFile = DiskCacheUtils.findInCache(image_url,  ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiscCache());
//then show it into image view
String file_target = "file://"+imageFile.getPath();
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(target, imageView);
```

However I have not found a way from documentation to do that in Glide.

Is it possible?

Comment: Lets follow up on your issue on GitHub: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/509

Comment: We're also migrating from UniversalImageLoader and we found loss of funcionability. For example, loading an image from cache is done with a single line: `ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiscCache().get(info.getDownload().getIcon())` and I have a Bitmap loaded from cache only (if doesn't exist, it doesn't download).

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa could you tell me, please, what was the reasons for this migration? And did you managed these shortcomings of Glide?

Comment: No, we ended up keeping the two image libraries, we had no time to investigate on this. Sorry

Comment: Yes, I had to keep UIL due that issue as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use below code

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(ImageUrl).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).into(imageView);
```